# Angular 8: Cannot read property 'database' of undefined @firebase

Tags: angular, firebase

I am upgrading angularfire2 v4 to @angular/fire v5.2.1 and firebase from v4 to v6.2.4 and get into trouble causing console to log this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'database' of undefined
    at Query.push../node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.cjs.js.Reference.databaseProp (index.cjs.js:14013)
    at Query.get [as database] (index.cjs.js:14179)
    at index.js:10
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at deepFreeze (index.js:7)
    at index.js:13
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at deepFreeze (index.js:7)
    at index.js:13
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

I have these in package json :

```
"firebase": "^6.2.4",
"firebase-admin": "^8.2.0",
 "@angular/fire": "^5.2.1",
```

I have implemented `AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)`

Everything was working in previous version.

I've updated logic for db queries etc, but didn't expect to have this error before, and now it is useless...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing the following and see if that works:

In your environment.ts :

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  firebase: {
    apiKey: 'your project api key',
    authDomain: 'your-project-id.firebaseapp.com',
    databaseURL: 'https://your-project-id.firebaseio.com',
    projectId: 'your-project-id',
    storageBucket: 'your-project-id.appspot.com',
    messagingSenderId: 'your-project-specific-info',
    appId: 'your app id'
  }
};
```

you will have to add your project details from firebase.

then refer environment object in `app.module.ts`:
        import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

see if that works for you

Comment: Please delete previously posted answer!

Comment: As I have explained in post, everything was working before update, I am not a beginner, I've done this 2 years ago when I first setup this project.
So this was done at that time just like you described.

Comment: I have also recently updated my firebase and @angular/fire version and it works fine for me. Can you please post the line of code where you are having this issue?

Comment: The line is posted in question, it is happening inside firebase library.

Comment: Found the issue, I was quering wrong list from db and therefore the issue appeared somehow. When I fixed it, it dissapeared...

Comment: But saw a lot of things happening like this unless you do the steps you mentioned here, so I will accept it as answer. @Vinita

Answer (score 0):

You might have done this already, but to double check, where is your firebase configuration kept? is it in environment.ts?